# Python: Custom package installation not importing module

Tags: python, git, pip, virtualenv

I'm having a problem with [this package](https://github.com/pgaref/HTTP_Request_Randomizer) that I installed in Python 3.5. After installing it, I try to run requestProxy.py but it won't import any of its own packages. Here's what I did, and what's happening.

I cloned it and created a private repo using [these instructions](https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository/).

I installed in an activated virtualenv, created without using sudo, using:

```
pip3 install -e HTTP_Proxy_Randomizer
```

Terminal said it installed ok.

I can find the egg link in my virtualenv's site-packages folder, but when I try to run the main file, it says:

```
from project.http.requests.parsers.freeproxyParser import freeproxyParser
ImportError: No module named project.http.requests.parsers.freeproxyParser
```

I had to write a setup.py for the package, which didn't seem to come with its own. I came up with:

```
setup(name='HTTP_Request_Randomizer',
  version='1.0',
  description='HTTP Proxy Request Randomizer',
  package_dir={'project': 'project','http':'project/http',\
  'requests':'project/http/requests','errors':'project/http/requests/errors',\
  'parsers':'project/http/requests/parsers','proxy':'project/http/requests/proxy'},
  packages=['project','http','requests','errors','parsers','proxy']
```

Here's the package structure:

[image]

pip3 freeze

gives me:

```
Complete output from command git config --get-regexp remote\..*\.url:
fatal: bad config file line 4 in /home/danny/.gitconfig

----------------------------------------
Error when trying to get requirement for VCS system Command "git config --get-regexp remote\..*\.url" failed with error code 128 in /home/danny/Documents/HTTP_Request_Randomizer, falling back to uneditable format
Could not determine repository location of /home/danny/Documents/HTTP_Request_Randomizer
Django==1.9.7
## !! Could not determine repository location
HTTP-Request-Randomizer==1.0
mysqlclient==1.3.7
```

So I want to have requestProxy.py install the other necessary packages and not fail at line 1. I'm sure this is a problem with my implementation and not the original author's coding. I was experimenting with this package a couple of weeks ago before I was aware of virtualenvs or pip install -e, and just copied it manually to site-packages. It worked then. Now I understand the concepts to do it more cleanly, but I can't get those to work.

It feels as though I have done something wrong with my git config or with my package_dir structure in setup.py, perhaps?

I've been pythoning for maybe a month and have a lot to learn. I normally find what I need on Stack Overflow without having to bother anyone, but after trying everything with this, I really need some help. Any advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was using Ninja IDE, and even though I entered the virtualenv for the project and restarted, it still wasn't recognizing it. I was able to run it from the terminal, and also in Pycharm and Liclipse.